# How to setup a PPTP tunnel to automatically reconnect after tunnel connection drops

Tags: windows-server-2012, pptp

I am currently connecting to a server via a pptp tunnel. I have a python script that downloads data from the tunnel. Every now and than the tunnel will be disconnected. I am wondering how do I automate the reconnection of the tunnel as the connection needs to be persistent. Currently I am using windows server 2012

Answer (score -1):

Could you hook to the [EventID = 20226](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733580(v=ws.10).aspx)? It works for Windows Server 2008. (At the moment, I can't find the docs for Windows Server 2012, but I think it is general enough to work there, too.)

From [answer describing auto-redial](https://superuser.com/a/557353/287473) you can use:

> 1. Using Task Scheduler, add a scheduled task.
> 2. Add two triggers for the scheduled task. One using the advanced XML query
>      
>      `<QueryList>
>        <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
>          <Select Path="Application">*[System[Provider[@Name='RasClient'] and
>      (EventID=20226)]] and *[EventData[Data[4]='829' or
>      '629']]</Select>
>        </Query>
>      </QueryList>`
>
>    and the other triggering on event log:
>      Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational, source: NetworkProfile,
>      Event ID: 10000
> 3. Add one action, to run "rasdial.exe" with parameters *vpn-name username password*

I have applied it to Windows 8.0 and works very well for me.